# Criar SelectList estatico e passar um item selecionado para a View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como enviar meu `selectList` "*status*" para a minha *View* `EditarUsuario`.

Criei a minha lista com os seguinte itens:

```
var list = new SelectList(new[]
{
     new{ID="2",Name="Selecione"},
     new{ID="1",Name="Ativo"},
     new{ID="0",Name="Inativo"},
}, "ID", "Name");
     ViewData["list"] = list;
```

Gostaria que viesse setado o status atual do usuário. Eu tenho em minha *model* o status vindo do banco:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
public int Status { get; set; }
```

Como viram, essa propriedade `Status` é um campo normal que traz 1 para Ativo e 0 para Inativo. Na minha *View* coloquei o `Helper` desta maneira:

```
@Html.DropDownList("list", ViewData["list"] as SelectList)
```

E ao verificar o HTML gerado esta assim:

```
<select id="list" name="list">
     <option value="2">Selecione</option>
     <option value="1">Ativo</option>
     <option value="0">Inativo</option>
</select>
```

Como eu faço para setar a lista assim?

```
<select id="list" name="list">
     <option value="2">Selecione</option>
     <option value="1" selected>Ativo</option>
     <option value="0">Inativo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seguindo o seu modelo, vou alterar apenas a forma de passar os dados para a `view`.
No lugar de um [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) irei utilizar o [SelectListItem](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=selectlistitem), e no lugar da `ViewData`, uma `ViewBag`.

Seu **controller** ficaria assim:

```
var list = new[]
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Selecione" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Ativo" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Inativo" },
};

ViewBag.Lista = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
```

Note que os valores agora são **Value** e **Text** e não **ID** e **Name** como antes.

E em sua `view`, basta chamar o `DropDown`, ficando assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("list", new SelectList(ViewBag.Lista, "ID", "Text", "1"))
```

No lugar do **1**, você coloca o **Value** do item que deverá estar o atributo `selected`. Desta forma, você pode preencher com uma lista de objetos retornados do banco de dados, apenas alterando a `ViewBag`.

> Pretendo alterar mostrando formas melhores de obter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou exatamente como eu gostaria. Muito obrigado @Randrade...

Comment: muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

`@Html.DropDownList` se torna bastante limitado quando você envia uma `SelectList` já pronta. Particularmente, prefiro que a *View* monte essa `DropDownList` pra mim da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, ((IEnumerable<Status>)ViewBag.StatusPossiveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
            Text = option.Name,
            Value = option.StatusId.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (option.StatusId == Model.Status)
        }), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Tendo acesso a cada `SelectListItem`, posso montar a lista com um Status já selecionado.

Obviamente, `Status` precisa ser uma classe pra funcionar:

```
ViewBag.StatusPossiveis = new List<Status> {
    new Status {StatusId = "1", Name="Ativo" },
    new Status {StatusId = "0", Name="Inativo" }
};
```

Comment: Suas dicas são valiosíssimas. Muito obrigado.